# If $1\leq p<q\leq\infty$, then $\ell^p\subsetneq\ell^q$ and $\left\|x\right\|_{\ell^q}\leq\left\|x\right\|_{\ell^p}$ for all $x\in\ell^p$.

Tags: real-analysis

My textbook says:

> Show that if $1\leq p<q\leq\infty$, then $\ell^p\subsetneq\ell^q$ and $\left\|x\right\|_{\ell^q}\leq\left\|x\right\|_{\ell^p}$ for all $x\in\ell^p$.

Suppose that I show these things. Isn't this a contradiction? I.e., let $x\in\ell^p$. Then $\left\|x\right\|_{\ell^q}\leq\left\|x\right\|_{\ell^p}<\infty$, which implies $x\in\ell^q$. Hence, $\ell^p\subseteq\ell^q$.

Comment: It's asking you to  show that $\ell^p \subset \ell^q$, but that $\ell^p \neq \ell^q$. No contradiction.

Comment: @Chris, thank you. I feel silly: I was reading $\subsetneq$ as "not a subset of".